# Change Fragment from Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to update a fragment in my activity from a static broadcast receiver - but it doesnt work

```
public static class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


           FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new Fragment1());

            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    }
```

there is a problem about getFragmentManager():

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFragmentManager() from the type Activity

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the static modifier from the class definition.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

this way you have access to the outer environment, and, if it is an instance of `Activity`, you can access `getFragmentManager`/`getSupportFragmentManager`.

Edit:

To register your BroadCast receiver programmatically

Declare as member variable

```
NetworkChangeReceiver mNetworkChangeReceiver;
```

onCreate:

```
mNetworkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver()
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
registerReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and onDestroy unregister it:

```
unregisterReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver);
```

Comment: then the broadcastReceiver itself does not work. it tells me that he could not find NetworkChangeReceiver class... I read something about this problem here, and they told me to make it static - then it worked, but now I have the current problem^^

Comment: In which circumstances does it say that?

Comment: When I remove the "static" - then it can't find the class..the class Network.. is inside my Main.java <receiver
        android:name=".Main$NetworkChangeReceiver" 
      >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: don't use the manifest to register it. Do it programmatically